# Frank setup finished, but cucumber test not working

Tags: iphone, ios, testing, cucumber, frank

I am setting up Frank and have done most of the setup.  I am trying to run the built in cucumber test that simply rotates the device.

I do `cucumber -d` while in `MyProject/Frank/` and get this:

```
cucumber -d
Feature: 
  As an iOS developer
  I want to have a sample feature file
  So I can see what my next step is in the wonderful world of Frank/Cucumber testing

  Scenario:                                             # features/my_first.feature:6
      Rotating the simulator for demonstration purposes
    Given I launch the app                              # features/step_definitions/launch_steps.rb:5
    Given the device is in landscape orientation        # features/my_first.feature:9
    Given the device is in portrait orientation         # features/my_first.feature:10
    Given the device is in landscape orientation        # features/my_first.feature:11
    Given the device is in portrait orientation         # features/my_first.feature:12

1 scenario (1 skipped)
5 steps (1 skipped, 4 undefined)
0m0.002s

You can implement step definitions for undefined steps with these snippets:

Given(/^the device is in landscape orientation$/) do
  pending # express the regexp above with the code you wish you had
end

Given(/^the device is in portrait orientation$/) do
  pending # express the regexp above with the code you wish you had
end
```

Just confused, and hoping I am setting things up right.  Thanks for any answers.

Comment: Can you post the feature file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out a bit ago.  I ran `cucumber -d` doing a "dry run" instead of just `cucumber` like a should have.  When I run `cucumber` everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

To use the Frank predefined steps, you should include the following line in the beginning of your "launch_steps.rb" file, which is normally located under "yourAppWorkspace/Frank/features/step_definitions":

```
require 'frank-cucumber/core_frank_steps.rb'
```

Then, if you run "cucumber" under the features directory your steps should run correctly.

You can also see all the predefined steps here: https://github.com/moredip/Frank/blob/master/gem/lib/frank-cucumber/core_frank_steps.rb